# What are some ideas for promoting our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

We have [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint) that people don't seem to visit much, yet it could really encourage participation in the site.

What do you think we can do to improve chat participation and get more of a community feel happening?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is possible, but... [image: chat box just like it is on meta].
Related thread @Alex found: [Is it technically trivial or possible to make the link to chat appear on the main site as well as the meta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98285/is-it-technically-trivial-or-possible-to-make-the-link-to-chat-appear-on-the-main)

Answer (score 2):

Use the site announcement to "advertise" meta or chat.

No screenshot, but this is the yellow banner that gets placed across the top of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Run a chat event on a topic that people find interesting, either about the site or SharePoint.

**[Suggestions can be made here.](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/what-chat-events-could-we-run)**

Answer (score 1):

Set a fun or interesting topic for our chat room. Only a small gesture but might give people a reason to enter.