# What chat events could we run?

Tags: discussion, chat

One of the features of chat is the ability to schedule a particular time for an 'event' that we can advertise on the site and get people interested!

Would people like to do this? If so, what topics would you like to discuss?

**One topic per answer please, and vote accordingly.**

Comment: Has anything come from this? I think these are awesome ideas!

Answer (score 4):

**Question Hitlist**

Ripping off @Stuart's idea: [Most wanted hitlist of unanswered questions?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/most-wanted-hitlist-of-unanswered-questions)

Set aside an hour, and choose a few unanswered questions. Then, we could try our best to figure out an answer for the questions.

Comment: +1 Just because it's got my name on it. :) Well, and it's a good idea I suppose.

Comment: I like this. It helps the site, gets attention on one of our goals for the site, and gives people something interesting to chew over.

Answer (score 3):

**Top user forum**

One or two of our high rep and/or MVP users discuss SharePoint topics "from the audience".

This would help to establish us as a place with valuable experts that actively participate in our site.

Answer (score 3):

As a sharepoint newcomer, I think it would be valuable to have a talk series on beginning sharepoint development, as many of people like me is baffled on how to begin developing. I'd rather not be only relying on responses from top contributors, but also would like to begin contributing.