# Can someone please turn off 'Highlander mode' in our chat room?

Tags: discussion

It looks like someone left our chat room in 'Highlander mode' - **There can be only one!**
(younger members please refer to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq4SqgxIKM0 for more details).

But seriously I am curious:

1. Why are you not logged in chat room while browsing SPSE?
2. In your own words: What is  main purpose of chat rooms here?

I found this past initiatives posted by @AlexAngas with no real success :(

- [What are some ideas for promoting our chat room?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-are-some-ideas-for-promoting-our-chat-room)
- [What chat events could we run?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/what-chat-events-could-we-run)

Answer (score 1):

1. Blocked at work for me... I think it was lumped in with Gaming.SE :/
2. It should be used for extended discussion.

For example, use chat when...

- There is a lot of troubleshooting needed to answer a question
- You want to get a lot of responses (polling, gathering opinions, etc)
- Just for fun!

That being said.. as a moderator, I'm going to try to stay in chat more.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:
Why do I have do log on to chat rooms seperatly? I know I need some reputation to talk there, there are more chatrooms than SO-portals.

I mean, few days ago I saw a 100 bounty in SO asking about SharePoint. This member also had account in SP. Why not asking there? I guess, it is same reason why noone is in chat.

Comment: Well programming questions can be asked on StackOverflow... So there is some overlap.