# What constitutes the recent activity in question?

Tags: support

As an example...

While checking active questions (clicking **active** tab) tagged by **Infopath**

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infopath

I see that a question

- [Filter a secondary datasource in infopath](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36758/filter-a-secondary-datasource-in-infopath)

shows "modified 1 hour ago" though the question, answers and comments have the newest timestamp from May 23-24.

What does constitute a recent modification, and how is it registered?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the last answer of Alan Richards has been [upvoted today](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8506/alan-richards?tab=reputation) today. It seems to be an activity as well, even it would not bring it to first page.

Okay, I found another strange thing: [this question](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/q/600/6478) claims last activity (hover over "Activity: " on date *and* time of my answer. But there was a comment later (to my answer). I'm unsure if my own (now self-deleted) comments to the question itself has been later or not.

And I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/incorrect-last-activity-user) old question on SO-meta where it is stated that if a user writes sth and delete it, only >10k rep users can see this.

Comment: It's me who upvoted his answer but after and due to seeing that thread being first in the list of active questions which draw my attention. But my main curiosity is whether this question is still worth to answer or it is out of any interest

Comment: @GennadyVanin--ГеннадийВанин Well, this way I have no idea what makes it active yesterday. Deciding of "worth to answer" is complicated: if right now no satisfieying answer (green mark/ comments) is there, it is worth - but if the OP has been away several month - you never know if it worked for him too.